# Distance of a point from the closest surface

Tags: geometry

Consider the situation in which I have a cuboid:

```
Cuboid[{0,0,0},{1,1,1}]
```

and a point in the cubiod

```
{0.9,0.4,0.6}
```

How do I find the *distance from the closest surface* of the cuboid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
SignedRegionDistance[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], {0.9, 0.4, 0.6}]
-0.1
```

the negative sign tells you that the query point is inside the region.